# Django Blog - Comment function shows dropdown menu for authors in form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I created a Django Blog and want to add a comment section. 
So far I created the Comment-models and it is possible to make comments. 
But for every user it shows a dropdown menu where they can chose the user which will displayed with the comment-posting, which should not be.
I tried to modifiy the Comments model and take out the 'author' in forms.py, but nothing works.
Does anyone have an idea what I could do here? 
I assume it must have something to do with the author, 
I also tried `author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)` but same result.
This is how my code looks like:

Forms.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('text',)
        #fields = ('author', 'text',)
```

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey(
      get_user_model(),
      on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

views.py

```
class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/user_posts.html' #<app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post


def add_comment_to_post(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('post-detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/add_comment_to_post.html', {'form': form})
```

If anybody could help me I would be so glad.

Greetings!

Comment: Can you show the *view* you are using?

Comment: please [edit] the question.

Comment: Alright, I just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)`. This should work fine too.
Most probably your problem is in `views.py`.

You should edit your post request so your model automatically gets user by: `request.user`

For your code you might need to add:
`comment.author = request.user` in views.py before saving comment.